# Sql Compact mistake while recovering data

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008, sql-server-ce

I have this code:

```
public void FillData()
    {
        // 1 step. Open connection
        string conection = @"Data Source=|DataDirectory|db.sdf;Persist Security Info=False;";
        try
        {
            SqlCeConnection c = new SqlCeConnection(conection);
            c.Open();

            // 2 step. Create new DataAdapter
            using (SqlCeDataAdapter a = new SqlCeDataAdapter("SELECT * FROM USER", c))
            {
                // 3 step. Use DataAdapter to fill table
                DataTable t = new DataTable();
                a.Fill(t);
                // 4 step. Render data on the DataGridView
                dataGridViewUsers.DataSource = t;
            }
        }
        catch (SqlException e)
        {
            MessageBox.Show(e.Message);
        }

    }
```

I can connect to the database, but the `SqlCeDataAdapter` launches this mistake:

`There was an error parsing the query. [Token line number = 1, Token line offset = 15, Token in error = USER]`

My database has a table named `USER`, so what's wrong with this code??

Answer (score 2, accepted):

USER is reserve word. Pass it like `[USER]` in your query. Your query should look like.

```
new SqlCeDataAdapter("SELECT * FROM [USER]", c))
```